# Why is IIS not serving our changes to layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Make a change to layout.cshtml
2. Upload the changed file to the server via Filezilla
3. Do a clean refresh of the site in Firefox
4. The problem is that the changes do not show up - instead we're served what seems like the previous version of the file.

Comment: Try cleaning your solution, delete any files in your `bin` directory, rebuild the solution and upload all of the files to the server rather than just the `layout` page.

Comment: Can you look in the server's IIS log file to see what the server says it is doing? A response code of 304 means "you have it already". Is there something caching the files between the server and the browser?

Comment: You don't have to re-publish your whole app. I usually make small changes on the view files and they are refreshed as expected. Try making a small change on you web.config (like adding an empty space and saving the file). This will force the app to re-compile.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The problem turned out to be along the lines of "is your machine plugged in?" See the "answer" below.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an attention-to-detail problem.  We were putting our changes into an html block that is conditionally displayed.

```
<footer id="footer">
    @if (someCondition) {
        <!-- our changes here -->
```

No wonder our changes didn't show up.